# MongoDB: `ChangeStream`'s `onChange` event doesn't get called for the first change after creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to implement a webpage that updates in the real time, reflecting any modification on a collection in MongoDB.

I'm prototyping a solution, and found out that after creating `collection.watch`, its `onChange` event doesn't get called for the first operation after the creation of `collection.watch`.

**Demo code**:

```js
import pkg from 'mongodb';
const { MongoClient } = pkg;

const uri = "mongodb://localhost";
export const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true 
});

(async function() {
  await client.connect();
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("test-coll");

  // changeStream onChange
  const changeHandler = async (changeDetail) => {
    console.log("Change event: ", changeDetail.operationType, changeDetail.fullDocument?.value);
  };
  const changeStream = collection.watch({ fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });
  changeStream.on('change', changeHandler);
  console.log("Finish Watch Setup.");

  // operations
  console.log("Insertting ABC.");
  await collection.insertOne({value: "ABC"});

  console.log("Insertting DEF.");
  await collection.insertOne({value: "DEF"});

  console.log("Deleting All.");
  await collection.deleteMany({});

})().catch(console.dir);
```

**Nodejs Output**:

```
Finish Watch Setup.
Insertting ABC.
Insertting DEF.
Deleting All.
Change event:  insert DEF
Change event:  delete undefined
Change event:  delete undefined
```

**Expected behavior**:

```
Change event:  insert ABC
```

should appear anywhere before

```
Change event:  insert DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Node is asynchronous, therefore your change stream creation is racing your first insert. You need to wait for the first batch of results to arrive from the change stream before inserting.

Comment: What exactly does "first batch of results" refer to?

Comment: It turns out if I schedule the operations using `setImmediate`, no change will be lost. `setImmediate(async function() { await collection.insertOne({asin: "ABC"}); })` or `setImmediate(function() { collection.insertOne({asin: "ABC"}); })` both works as expected.